# Question about application of Eisenstein criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification, factoring

I have the following problem: Prove that $P(x)=x^k+5x^{k-1}+3$ with an arbitrary integer $k>1$ cannot be factored into two polynomials $Q$ and $R$ with integer coefficients and degree at least 1, i.e. so that $P(x)=Q(x)\cdot R(x) \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

My idea is as follows: I know about [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) whose conclusion is exactly what we want to prove. Sadly, we cannot use it right away. But I read that you could also apply it if you look at the polynomial modulo an arbitrary integer (if there was a factorisation before, then that one still holds modulo that integer). So I tried looking at $P(x)$ modulo 5 and the outcome is the polynomial $x^k+3$. If we then choose $p=3$ to apply Eisenstein's criterion, everything works perfectly and by the aforementioned criterion, there are no $Q$ and $R$ as mentioned in the problem modulo 5, hence not in the whole integers. Is this right?

Similarly, is it right to consider $x^3-2x^2+x-8$ modulo 5 again to get $x^3-2x^2-4x+2$ and then choose $p=2$ and apply Eisenstein again to conclude that $x^3-2x^2-4x+2$ and hence $x^3-2x^2+x-8$ cannot be factored either?

That whole area is new to me so advice would be much approved.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't combine these two irreducibility criterion as you have attempted.  For instance, consider the polynomial $(x+1)(x+2) = x^2 + 3x + 2$.  By the same reasoning as in your post, mod $3$, we have $x^2 + 2$ to which we could then apply Eisenstein's criterion with $p = 2$.  But this is absurd, because the polynomial we started with is clearly reducible.

Comment: The problem is, that when you go to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ that there are no prime elements left, because everything (apart from 0 of course) is a unit. Hence you cannot apply both.

Answer (score 2):

Use this extension of the Eisenstein's Criterion (unfortunately I have not found a reference, however the proof is more or less
the same of the original Eisenstein's Criterion where $k=n$).

Let $P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. If there exist a prime number $p$  and an integer $1\leq k\leq n$, such that
$$p\mid a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{k-1},\quad p\nmid a_{k}\quad\mbox{and}\quad p^2 \nmid a_0,$$
then $P$  has an irreducible factor of degree $d\geq k$.

For $P(x)=x^n+5x^{n-1}+3$ with $n>1$, take $p=3$ and $k=n-1$ then by the above criterion $P$  has an irreducible factor of degree $d\geq n-1$.
The case $d=n-1$ is impossible because $P$ has no factors in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $1$ ($P$ ha no integer roots).  Hence $d=n$ and $P$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: The theorem in the text you cite start with "Let $f(x)=a_nx^n +\cdots+a_0\in\mathbb Z[x]$ be a polynomial and suppose there is a prime $p$ such that $p$ does not divide $a_n$, $p$ divides $a_i$ for $i=0,\dots,n-1$, ..." How do you show $p|a_{n-1}$ in your example?

Comment: @Pierre-Yves Gaillard You are right. I will try to find a correct reference.

Comment: [Extended Eisenstein's Criterion](http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=623&lmm=0).